# I've lost my South African passport and I had a German visa cause I've statyed in Berlin for a year, what must I do?

Tags: visas, passports, south-african-citizens

Can I apply for a new passport and take it to the German consulate in Pretoria and can they give me my old visa?
A copy or duplicate of my old Visa?

Comment: Please don't use all caps.

Comment: What is "Pta"? Did you check the consulate's website?

Answer (score 1):

My experience (admittedly not with SA and Germany) is that you will make a new visa application. The only way a duplicate would be issued is if you were able to present the original visa, which of course you can't do.